# Search for specific element in sorted array

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, search-algorithms, discrete-mathematics

> Given sorted array $A[1..n]$. We want to find an element such that
> $A[i]=3i+2$  in $O(\log n)$(binary search).

I trying to relate to problem finding element in sorted array $A$ such that $A[i]=i$, but i can't use that technique to solve mentioned problem. Any hint be appreciated.

Comment: Which algorithms do you know that work for sorted arrays in $O(\log n)$ time?

Comment: Binary search..

Comment: Did it not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $B[i] = (A[i]-2)/3$. Now you want to find an index $i$ such that $B[i] = i$.

Comment: Runtime will be $O(n)$? becuase we must  read each $A[i]$

Comment: You say that you knew how to solve the problem of finding $i$ such that $A[i] = i$. This appears to be identical to your problem (unless you assumed more about $A$).

Comment: Yes i know, but the problem is, for calculate each $B[i]$ we need $O(n)$ time. But i say we must do it in $O(\log n)$.

Comment: You don't need to calculate all of $B$. Whenever the algorithm queries $B[i]$, you answer with $(A[i]-2)/3$.

Comment: Thanks. it's amazing answer.